# WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Tags: socket.io

One of the chat user constantly get `error` event with the following explanation

```
 SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
```

The bad thing is that I cannot find out why this happens (do not have access to machine, and on my machine using IE causes no errors). It is so annoying. More to add upon getting this error the server receives `disconnect` event with a big delay, causing **some** messages from him to fall into the void and not get delivered to me (so in result I receive some of them, not all).

This happens only for him. What I know is that he uses Internet Explorer 12 and `polling` as transport. I have tried to force `websocket` or other transports, but only `polling` succeed.

Somewhere by googling for explanation on this error I found that it is some kind of browser specific issue that may or may not happen.

What may be the reason for abnormal terminations? What may be the cure to it?

Comment: is there a way for me to find out?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same message but with Edge browser and WCF's WebSocket server implementation, all running on the same machine.

Using Fiddler 4, I've noted that the server never ever sends a Ping. The browser sends several Pongs and then seems to give up. At that point the following message appears in Developer Tools console... SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally.

I suspect something on the user's machine is preventing websockets from working normally. Try using Fiddler 4 to see if you can identify anything unusual.

Comment: I have managed to solve it by moving to https and adding *allowUpgrades* option to *true*